# java/jdbc timeout in clojure

Tags: testing, jdbc, clojure, timeoutexception

I am trying to add timeout to `jdbc/query` and `jdbc/execute!`. Somewhere in the web I found that both functions take `:timeout` as an option. Documention also says the options are passed to `prepare-statment` which takes in `:timeout` as an option.

My function calls look like,

```
(jdbc/query db-read-spec query {:timeout 2})

(jdbc/execute! db-write-spec query {:timeout 2})
```

Is this how it is done? If yes, How do I test this?

If there is different way of doing this which is testable, that works too.

Comment: Are you asking, because it does not work? A naive test would be use an unreasonable small timeout and assume it would time out.

Answer (score 2):

The `:timeout` option causes `.setQueryTimeout` to be called on the `PreparedStatement` used under the hood of `clojure.java.jdbc`. It is in *seconds*, not milliseconds, so your query would have to be extremely slow for a timeout of 2,000 seconds (just over half an hour) to take effect.

JDBC supports several different timeouts across several of its classes. For example, `javax.sql.DataSource` supports `.setLoginTimeout` (also in seconds), as does `java.sql.DriverManager`.

There are also database-specific options you can add to the connection string (which you can add as additional key/value pairs in your "db-spec") to control lower-level timeouts. For example, MySQL supports `connectionTimeout` and `socketTimeout` in the connection string -- and both of those are in **milliseconds**. `clojure.java.jdbc` allows for those to be provided in your "db-spec" hash map as `:connectTimeout` and `:socketTimeout` keys respectively.

Note that `clojure.java.jdbc` is considered "Stable" at this point and all current and future development effort is focused on [`next.jdbc`](https://github.com/seancorfield/next-jdbc/) at this point. `next.jdbc` makes it easier to use the `loginTimeout` since it operates on JDBC objects directly, so the whole (Java) API is available as well. It also has built-in support for connection pooling and is, overall, simpler and faster than `clojure.java.jdbc`.

Comment: Found out the :timeout takes in seconds little later. @Sean Corfield Thanks for the detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [query-hint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-execution-time) on mysql-select-queries (time in ms)

`SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(1000) */ * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 WHERE....`

then you can just wrap your queries:

```
(defn timed-query [db query t]
  (j/query db [(str (subs query 0 6)
                    (format " /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(%s) */ " t)
                    (subs query 7))]))
```

and test:

```
(deftest test-query-timeout
  (is (thrown? Exception (timed-query db "select * from Employees where id>5" 1))))
```

you should use much-complex queries for this to work with 1ms;

Answer (score 0):

I figure out a work around to test this out. Since I use postgres I could leverage `select pg_sleep(time-in-seconds)`

And my test looks like

```
(is (thrown-with-msg? PSQLException #"ERROR: canceling statement due to user request"
                          (fetch-or-save "select pg_sleep(3)")))
```